# How to add columns to a dataframe without using withcolumn

Tags: pyspark

I need to loop through a json file, flatten the results and add a column to a dataframe in each loop with respective values. But the end result will have around ~2000 columns. So, using withColumn to add the columns is extremely slow. Is their any other alternative to add columns to a dataframe?

Sample Input json:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "12345",
    "Timestamp": "20140101",
    "Usefulness": "Yes",
    "Code": [
      {
        "event1": "A",
        "result": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "1A35B",
    "Timestamp": "20140102",
    "Usefulness": "No",
    "Code": [
      {
        "event1": "B",
        "result": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My output should be:

```
ID     Timestamp  Usefulness  Code_event1  Code_result

12345  20140101   Yes          A           1
1A35B  20140102   No           B           1
```

The json file I am working on is huge and consists of many columns. So, withColumn is not feasible in my case.

EDIT:

Sample code:

```
# Data file
df_data = spark.read.json(file_path)  

# Schema file
with open(schemapath) as fh:
    jsonschema = json.load(fh,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

I am looping through the schema file and in the loop I am accessing the data for a particular key from the data DF (df_data). I am doing this because my data file has multiple records so I cant loop through the data json file or it will loop through every record.

```
def func_structs(json_file):
    for index,(k,v) in enumerate(json_file.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
           srccol = k
           func_structs(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
           srccol = k
           func_lists(v) # Separate function to loop through list elements to find nested elements
        else:
            try:
                df_data = df_data.withColumn(srcColName,df_Data[srcCol])
            except:
                df_data = df_data.withColumn(srcColName,lit(None).cast(StringType()))

func_structs(jsonschema)
```

I am adding columns to the data DF (df_data) itself.

Comment: From your expected output, I see, you need a straight conversion of JSON -> dataframe. No extra columns added. It would be great if you can post the code that you have tried till now on this. That would be a great kickstart for the solvers.Fr

Comment: Hello @Surabhi so actually your dataframe will scale horizontally? I mean is there any particular reason that you need this schema and not somethis like `(id, timestamp, usefulness, code_event_id, code_result)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Spark's built-in `json` parser to read the json into a DF:

```
df = (sqlContext
      .read
      .option("multiLine", True)
      .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
      .json('file:///mypath/file.json')) # change as necessary
```

The result is as follows:

```
+--------+-----+---------+----------+
|    Code|   ID|Timestamp|Usefulness|
+--------+-----+---------+----------+
|[[A, 1]]|12345| 20140101|       Yes|
|[[B, 1]]|1A35B| 20140102|        No|
+--------+-----+---------+----------+
```

The second step is then to break out the struct inside the `Code` column:

```
df = df.withColumn('Code_event1', f.col('Code').getItem(0).getItem('event1'))
df = df.withColumn('Code_result', f.col('Code').getItem(0).getItem('result'))
df.show()
```

which gives

```
+--------+-----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    Code|   ID|Timestamp|Usefulness|Code_event1|Code_result|
+--------+-----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|[[A, 1]]|12345| 20140101|       Yes|          A|          1|
|[[B, 1]]|1A35B| 20140102|        No|          B|          1|
+--------+-----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

EDIT:

Based on comment below from @pault, here is a neater way to capture the required values (run this code after load statement):

```
df = df.withColumn('Code', f.explode('Code'))
df.select("*", "Code.*")
```

Comment: how about `df.select("*", "Code.*")` instead of the `getItem`s for the second step?

Comment: hmm, I get the follwoing error when I try that code: `Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(Code)`;`

Comment: maybe I need to explode Code first then use your code?